# How to skip some input parameters' set in MT4 StrategyTester optimization mode, if constraints were not met?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

I've 3 different input parameters : `P1 [1..10], P2 [1..10]` and `P3 [3..10]`. The constraints are the following : **`P1 < P2 < P3`**.

Some potential solutions should be discarded right away when the constraints are not respected. For instance when `P1 = 2`, `P2 = 1` and `P3 = 4`.

Is there a way to accomplish such thing with MetaTrader optimization ?
( eventually using an `OnTesterPass()` function ? )

I'm losing a lot of time during my optimization because of that and I'd like to find a way to discard or skip directly the potential solution when the constraints are not respected.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int OnInit(){
   if(P1<P2 && P2<P3){} // OK
   else{
      printf("%i %s - parameters SKIPPED, !(P1<P2<P3)",__LINE__,__FUNCTION__);
      return(INIT_FAILED);
   }
}
```

That is all.

The `printf()` is not called during optimization.

Either **`INIT_FAILED`** or **`INIT_PARAMTERS_INCORRECT`** stop the optimization of a particular set and the [ MT4 Strategy Tester ] goes right to the next set of parameters.

You do not need `OnTesterPass()` because it is called after test is done, `OnInit()` is automatically called Event-handler right upon entering a new set of optimisation parameters into such a test run.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for